# How to concat two lists in Linq when the underlying anonymous types are similar?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this code:

```
var listA = from s in Students 
            select new {FirstName= s.FirstName, LastName = s.LastName};

var listB = from t in Teachers 
            select new {FirstName= t.FirstName, LastName = t.LastName};


var teachersAndStudents = listA.Concat(listB); // This fails because types are not same
var someName = teachersAndStudents.First().FirstName;
```

How can I create the `teachersAndStudents` list, not losing the types?

Not losing the types means that `teachersAndStudents.First().FirstName` should be valid at the last line.

Comment: Do they share a base class?

Comment: Why not create a named type for that?

Comment: What are the types of `Students.FirstName`, `Teacher.LastName` etc? Anonymous types with the same property names and types should unify to the same type.

Comment: In addition to the comments above, which will both work, you could put an interface over them.

Comment: @Dmitry in my situation I can't use named types. Because there's lots of combinations that I don't want to create a named type for each one.

Comment: As @Rawling already commented, you need to post the types of the FirstName and LastName members of both students and teachers.

Comment: @Rawling you're right, this code works on Linq2Object. I think the problem is with Linq2Sql. But I'm not at the work now to test if the problem was because of Linq2Sql or not.

Answer (score 6):

This code works well, your problem in something else

```
   class Student
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; } 
    }

    class Teacher
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; } 
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listA = from s in new List<Student>()
                        select new { FirstName = s.FirstName, LastName = s.LastName };

            var listB = from t in new List<Teacher>()
                        select new { FirstName = t.FirstName, LastName = t.LastName };

            var teachersAndStudents = listA.Concat(listB); 
            var someName = teachersAndStudents.First().FirstName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: It answers the question that was asked with the information that was provided. If you think this doesn't answer the question perhaps you would care to elaborate why you think it doesn't, instead of just saying "it doesn't." ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - This "answer" is nothing more than a sentence saying "your problem in something else". Without knowing what `Teachers` and `Students` are in the original question, this code snippet could well be identical

Comment: So basically you're saying that until we have the types of firstname and lastname, there is no point in answering.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - No, but there isn't any answer for this since we don't know *why* it fails, There are two "answers" on this question that both show that the code that the OP provided should work. Given the amount of time that has passed since this answer and also since the OP was active around the time this was posted, I would imagine this hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: There *is* an answer to this question but it's still going to be based on assumptions, although very strong assumptions. The correct answer with the information we've been given is that either FirstName or LastName across students and teachers are of different types, thus rendering the two anonymous types different. That is the only real conclusion we can draw if the provided code is correct. As such I agree that the two answers here should've been posted as comments though there already exists comments that cover this ground.

Comment: That doesn't make these answers wrong, just bad. I really don't like answers (or comments for that matter) that says "It must be something else". If you know it must be something else, consider what that else may be and post that. If you can't, then most likely you can't answer (or comment).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - I think we are in agreement, I think the difference would be that I would see this as not an answer (I do agree that it is VLQ). Perhaps this is a discussion for meta but then I don't know what that would achieve. (Probably will delete this comment later today)

Comment: Ping me if you do. I too think we are in agreement :)

Answer (score 3):

The line with call to Concat cannot fail due to types because two anonymous types are the same. Try this piece of code and you will see it as well:

```
var listA = from s in Students
            select new { FirstName = s.FirstName, LastName = s.LastName };

var listB = from t in Teachers
            select new { FirstName = t.FirstName, LastName = t.LastName };

Console.WriteLine(listA.First().GetType().Name);
Console.WriteLine(listB.First().GetType().Name);
```

In my case, this code prints:

```
<>f__AnonymousType0`2
<>f__AnonymousType0`2
```

This proves that the compiler has generated the same actual type for the statements that require anonymous type.

Can you attach the error you're receiving?

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: I can't post this code in comments...

Comment: The code is irrelevant though, You could post a comment containing the first and last sentences, include a dotnetfiddle link if you wish

Comment: Why is the code irrelevant? It proves that the problem must be somewhere other than what was posted in the question. Most likely the type of the FirstName and LastName properties is different but since no information about that is posted, this is all anyone have to go on. If we can assume the firstname and lastname types are the same across those two types, which is not a bad assumption to be honest considering the OP wants to combine items into the same list, then this code would work, when it obviously (according to the OP) doesn't.

Comment: I didn't know about this feature of compiler which creates one type for both. So the problem should be somewhere else in my code. Perhaps it's because I'm using Linq2Sql instead of Linq2Objects which this answer assumes.